# Object non close IIS

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, vb6

I have a website which I want to run on IIS Windows XP , but on the login page when I try to connect I get this error from file (Access.asp)

Here is the code of file  :

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<!--#include file="PerformClear.asp"-->
<!--#include file="expire.vbs"-->
<%'Déclarations de toutes les variables de cette page
dim login, password, numu
dim sql, rs , conn
'Response.Redirect("PleaseWait.htm")
login = Trim(Replace(Request.Form ("login"),"'","''"))
password = Trim(Replace(Request.Form ("password"),"'","''"))
'Response.write (nom)
if (login<>"") and (password<>"") then
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Cadre WHERE Utilisateur='" & login & "' & pw='" &            password & "'"
Set rs = Session("conn").Execute(SQL)
If not rs.eof then 'alors l'utilisateur est bien identifié'
    session("nom")=rs("utilisateur") 'pour se rappeler de l'utilisateur 
    session("num")=rs("code_cadre") 
    numu=rs("code_cadre")
    rs.Close
    set rs=nothing
    Response.Redirect "."
else
    rs.Close
    set rs=nothing
    Response.Redirect "erreur.asp?Code=1"
end if  
rs.close
set rs = nothing
else
Response.Redirect("erreur.asp?Code=1")
end if
%>
```

The error i get is :

> ADODB.Connection error '800a0e78'  Operation Failed and Non authorized
>   because Object Closed

Please help I'm lost.

Comment: So ? No one knows the answer to that?

Answer (score 0):

You should not store the ADODB connection in the Session object, this forces thread affinity which is harmful and is very inefficient.

So long as you use the same connection string it will be pooled automatically, connect and close new connections as and when you need them in the page.

Additionally your using an ampersand here instead of `AND`:

```
"SELECT * FROM Cadre WHERE Utilisateur='" & login & "' & pw='" & password & "'"
```

Change to:

```
"SELECT * FROM Cadre WHERE Utilisateur='" & login & "' AND pw='" & password & "'"
```